# How to check all order item already invoiced

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, invoice

Currently I can check if order already has invoice like this:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load('1');
$hasInvoice = $order->getInvoiceCollection()->count();
if($hasInvoice > 0) return true;
else return false;
```

You can create invoice for all order items or just some of the order item. And the problem is i need to know if all the order item has already been invoiced?

Comment: this would help you - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24700/how-to-get-invoice-from-order-item